# Using neural network for "features matching" binary classification

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, classification, binary

We have a dataset of numerical features from two images and we want to check if these images match or not using only these features.
Basically we have have these columns:

- fA1, fA2, ..., fA14: 14 features from image A
- fB1, fB3, ..., fB14: 14 features from image B

We want to predict if image A match image B (y=1) or not (y=0). So it's a features matching problem.

The main usecase is for face recognition using this framework:
[BERND HEISELE](https://www.cs.ait.ac.th/~mdailey/cvreadings/Heisele-Face.pdf)

So is there any neural networks architecture known for this situation (we have a 7 million annotated training set) ?

N.B: we don't have any images, we have only numerical features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, your dataset is of pairs of images and a binary classification of their pairing?

There are models using an architecture named **Siamese Neural Networks** which are used exactly for this task of determining similarity.

You can start by reading the following article: [Learning to Compare Image Patches via Convolutional Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.03641). They are using Siamese architecture to compare between different image patches (similar to what you are describing):

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Mark.F for your response. Our dataset is not a pair of images, it's a pair of numerical features computed from images. We don't have the images themselves, thus we cannot use CNNs.

Comment: You can still use CNNs, just not in the traditional meaning - you can use 1d convolutions. However, depending on the number of features, you might even be able to use fully-connected models (dense). You can still learn from the Siamese architectures, just replace the inner models from the standard CNN to your 1d CNN or dense model.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you don't have the images, only the features.

In the end, it's still a binary classification (same object / different object).

If both objects have the same structure, you should apply the Siamese Neural Networks concept, that means, the same network pre-processing both objects before the decision layer.

This network don't need to be a CNN. It could something as simple as fully connected neural network.

You just need to be sure both networks are exactly the same (share the same weights) all the time.